# How to drawLabels true only for current node and connected node by hovering on current Node in sigmaJs?

Tags: javascript, angular, sigma.js

I am using overNode event of sigmaJs
My Setting object

```
settings: {
        autoRescale: ["nodePosition", "nodeSize"],
        labelThreshold: 0,
        adjustSizes: true,
        fixed: true,
        labelHoverBGColor: "#f45b3d",
        nodeMargin: 50,
        nodesPowRatio: 1,
        defaultNodeBorderColor: '#000000',
        minArrowSize: 7,
        drawLabels: false,
      }
```

```
this.s.bind("overNode", (d) => {
      this.s.graph.edges().forEach((e) => {
        if (e.target === d.data.node.id || e.source === d.data.node.id) 
        {
          e.color = "#407784";
          e.size = 3;
        } else {
          e.color = e.originalColor;
          e.size = 1;
        }
      });
      this.s.refresh();
    })
```

I can hover and highlighted the connected node with the overNode but that nodeLabel is not displaying.

In the setting, I have assigned drawLabels false initially as I don't want to display label initially.

So if I hover on any node I want to display label for the connected label to the hover only.

Comment: what version of angular do you use? And do you have a stackblitz?

Comment: I'm using angular 7 and no I don't have stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below logic:

```
this.s.graph.nodes().forEach(n => {
      if (n.id !== d.data.node.id) {
        n.color = "#D3D3D3";
        n.label = '';
      } else {
        n.label = n.displayLabel;
      }
    })
```

The first time, When you push data into nodes just pass the empty string as a label and add another property display label.

Please make sure that drawLabels property is true and on overNode drawLabels must be true and outNode drawLabels must be false.

Now Above for loop will use that displayLabel property whenever you want to display a label.